# How to make my code more simple using python 

Tags: python, dictionary

this is my code:

```
def set_floor_point(self,floor_point=None):
    if self.data.get('stage'):
        self.data['stage'] = {}
    stage_number = self.get_stage_number()
    floor_number = self.get_floor_number()

    if self.data['stage'].get(stage_number):
        self.data['stage'][stage_number] = {}

    if self.data['stage'][stage_number].get('floor_point'):
        self.data['stage'][stage_number]['floor_point'] = {}

    if self.data['stage'][stage_number]['floor_point'].get(floor_number):
        self.data['stage'][stage_number]['floor_point'][floor_number] = {}


    self.data['stage'][stage_number]['floor_point'][floor_number] = floor_point
```

and the dict i create when first time is like this :

```
stage = 
{
    0:{
        'floor':{
            0:{
                'floor_point':0,
                'gift':{}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i think my code is not very good , it is too Cumbersome,

so Are someone know more simple way ,

thanks

Comment: By default, the `dict` `get()` method returns `None` when the key is not present, so perhaps you meant `if not some_dict.get():`. Even that can be fooled by key *values* which are logically `False`, like `0`, `''`, and `[]`. Probably better to use `if not some_dict.has_key()` or `if key not in some_dict`.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(
  lambda: collections.defaultdict(dict)))
data['stage'][3]['floor_point'][2] = 5
print data
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. A recurring theme in your code is:

```
if some_dict.get(key):
    some_dict[key] = {}
```

That means: if `some_dict` has a key `key` and `some_dict[key]` is a truthy value, then replace `some_dict[key]` by `{}`. If `some_dict` doesn't have a key `key` or `some_dict[key]` is a falsy value (`None`, `0`, `False`, `[]` etc.), then do nothing.

If that is what you wanted, you could clarify your like this:

```
def replace_value_by_empty_dict(d, key):
    if d.get(key):
        d[key] = {}
...
replace_value_by_empty_dict(self.data, 'stage')
etc.
```

But if that's not what you intended (the code will break if one of the `if`s is true), you might want to phrase the problem in english words or pseudocode to clarify the structure of the problem.

And have a look at [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: IMHO, using `get()` to test for the presence of a dictionary key this way is a poor practice -- whether it's wrapped in a function or not.

Comment: @martineau: You're right, we have `key in some_dict` which tests for the presence of a key. I aimed at clarifying what zjm1126's code actually does. I doubt that it's what he intended.